# Filling DF's NaN/Missing data from another DF

Tags: python, dataframe, missing-data, fillna

I have two data frames:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Group': ['xx', 'yy', 'zz', 'x', 'x', 'x','z','y','y','y','y'],
                    'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                    'Value': [5, 3, 4, 7, 1, 3, 6, 5, 9, 5, 4]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
                    'Group': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'y'],
                    'Repeat': [3, 2, 1, 2]}).
```

All the `NaN` of `df1["Name"]` have to fill by `df2["Name"]` by matching `"Group"`. Can repeat matching and filling by `"Repeat"` times.

Desired output:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Group': ['xx', 'yy', 'zz', 'x', 'x', 'x','z','y','y','y','y'],
                   'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
                   'Value': [5, 3, 4, 7, 1, 3, 6, 5, 9, 5, 4]})
```

Also looking for the fastest run time.

I did this

```py
for index2, row2 in df2.iterrows():
    for i in range(0, row2[2]):
        for index1 in df1.index:
            if df1.iloc[index1, 1] == row2[1] and df1.iloc[ndex1, 1] == 'NaN':
                df1.iloc[ndex1, 1] = row2[0]
                break
```

Looking for simpler and faster solution.

Comment: Hi Parvez! Welcome to StackOverflow. Would you be able to paste the actual datasets into your question (using `df.to_dict()`)

Comment: also, in df2, how do you decide if y, 2 is A or B?

Comment: If anyone need. df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Group': ['xx', 'yy', 'zz', 'x', 'x', 'x','z','y','y','y','y'], 'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], 'Value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 'Group': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'y'], 'Repeat': [3, 2, 1, 2]}).

Comment: see my question above

Comment: @Itération122442 already added

Comment: @Mark as answer of your 2nd question. Doesn't matter the sequence of A & B as long the NaN been filled up matching 'Group,.

Comment: I don't think you understand. In the case of df1, the last four rows. There are  4 ys. there is no y, 4 row in df2

Comment: In df2 there are 2 ys with repeat 2. Add the repeat of ys you will get 4.

Comment: you might have to break things down further, and explain them again. The four y values are 5, 9, 5, 4. Explain to me like I'm 5 how I get from those to A, A, B, B